# Understanding what the check on the SERVER variable is for

Tags: php

i was just going through the source code of PhileCMS and came across the following script:

see this code Here:

```
if (isset($this->server['PHP_SELF'])) {
    $url = preg_replace('/index\.php(.*)?$/', '', $this->server['PHP_SELF']);
}
```

now `$this->server` is actually `$_SERVER`;

I want to know, what is the above if condition really checking for ?

The entire script can be seen **[HERE](https://github.com/PhileCMS/Phile/blob/master/lib/Phile/Core/Router.php#L75)**

Comment: it's checking if PHP_SELF exists. if it is, mangle it.

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is the path to the currently running script.  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: @RocketHazmat saw the documentation , i know that , just wanted to know what the if condition was for !

Comment: I'm not sure *why*, but it's removing `/index.php` (and everything after it) from the URL.  See this quick demo: https://eval.in/450554

Comment: @RocketHazmat add that as an answer ! thats correct .

Comment: Did you check the *name* of the function this code is a part of?  `getBaseUrl()`.  That code is getting the "path" to the index.php file.  It's getting the location this app is installed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` contains:

> The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root.

Now I'm not sure *why* this code exists or why it's checking `isset` (I'm pretty sure there will never be a case where `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is not set), but what it is doing is taking the URL and *removing* `index.php` and everything after it.

For example if you navigated to: `http://example.com/foo/bar/index.php/info?test=123` then `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` would be `/foo/bar/index.php/info` (the query string is not included).  So the shown `preg_replace` statement would remove `/index.php/info` thus leaving `/foo/bar`.

**UPDATE**: Did you happen to notice the *name* of the function this code is a part of?  `public function getBaseUrl()`.  It's getting the path (or "base URL") of the index.php.  It's figuring out the path to where it's installed to.